# Pass data from HTTP to node.js to TCP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, socket.io

I recently started using Socket.io, and node.js as a result, and I am kind of stuck. I do not even know if this is a practical solution for my application, but hopefully someone can help.

All I have here is a webpage with a checkbox, which reports it's status to the node console, and then when a TCP client connects, it receives the status as well.

I am wondering how I would go about making this event continuous, so that the TCP client constantly receives updates on the status of the checkbox.

If anyone has any idea, please let me know, and sorry for the long code...

### Server Code:

```
var net = require('net');
var app = require('express')();         <!-- These are mandatory variables -->
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 4040;
GLOBAL.MYVAR = "Hello world";
var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(PORT, HOST);


app.get('/', function(req, res){           <!-- This sends the html file -->
//send the index.html file for all requests
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});

http.listen(3001, function(){    <!-- Tells the HTTP server which port to use -->

  console.log('listening for HTTP on *:3001');   <!-- Outputs text to the console -->
  console.log('listening for TCP on port ' + PORT);
});

<!-- everything below this line are actual commands for the actual app -->

io.on('connection', function(socket) // Opens the socket

{ 
  socket.on('checkbox1', function(msg){  // Creates an event
     console.log(msg); // displays the message in the console
     MYVAR = msg; // Sets the global variable to be the contents of the message recieved
  });

});


server.on('connection', function(socket){ // Opens the socket for the TCP connection
    socket.write(MYVAR);   
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

### Client code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket IO Test</title>

<form action="">
  <input type='checkbox' onclick='checkbox1(this);'>Checkbox1</label>
</form>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  var number = 0;

function checkbox1(cb) {
    socket.emit('checkbox1', 'checkbox 1 = ' + cb.checked);
    return false;
   }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that you don't have a way to reference the TCP socket. Once you do have a reference it is as easy as receiving a message and sending it.

This will work for a single client.

```
    var net = require('net');
    var app = require('express')();         <!-- These are mandatory variables -->
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
    var s;
    var HOST = 'localhost';
    var PORT = 4040;
    GLOBAL.MYVAR = "Hello world";
    var server = net.createServer();
    server.listen(PORT, HOST);


    app.get('/', function(req, res){           <!-- This sends the html file -->
    //send the index.html file for all requests
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

    });

    http.listen(3001, function(){    <!-- Tells the HTTP server which port to use -->

      console.log('listening for HTTP on *:3001');   <!-- Outputs text to the console -->
      console.log('listening for TCP on port ' + PORT);
    });

    <!-- everything below this line are actual commands for the actual app -->

    io.on('connection', function(socket) // Opens the socket

    {
      socket.on('checkbox1', function(msg){  // Creates an event
         console.log(msg); // displays the message in the console
         MYVAR = msg; // Sets the global variable to be the contents of the message recieved
         s.write(MYVAR, 'utf-8');
      });

    });


    server.on('connection', function(socket){ // Opens the socket for the TCP connection
        s = socket;
        s.write(MYVAR, 'utf-8');
    }).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

This will work for multiple clients.

```
    var net = require('net');
    var app = require('express')();         <!-- These are mandatory variables -->
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
    var sockets = [];
    var HOST = 'localhost';
    var PORT = 4040;
    GLOBAL.MYVAR = "Hello world";
    var server = net.createServer();
    server.listen(PORT, HOST);


    app.get('/', function(req, res){           <!-- This sends the html file -->
    //send the index.html file for all requests
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

    });

    http.listen(3001, function(){    <!-- Tells the HTTP server which port to use -->

      console.log('listening for HTTP on *:3001');   <!-- Outputs text to the console -->
      console.log('listening for TCP on port ' + PORT);
    });

    <!-- everything below this line are actual commands for the actual app -->

    io.on('connection', function(socket) // Opens the socket

    {
      socket.on('checkbox1', function(msg){  // Creates an event
         console.log(msg); // displays the message in the console
         MYVAR = msg; // Sets the global variable to be the contents of the message recieved
         for (var i = 0; i < sockets.length; i++) {
          if(sockets[i]) {
            sockets[i].write(MYVAR, 'utf-8');
          }
        }
      });

    });


    server.on('connection', function(socket){ // Opens the socket for the TCP connection
        sockets.push(socket);
        socket.write(MYVAR, 'utf-8');
    }).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Comment: First off thank you so much for your help, but why did you change

 var io = require('socket.io')(http); to var io = require('socket.io')(3000);?

I tried it, but it does lot log it in the console with it set to 3000, but when I change it back to http, it throws a "missing error handler"? Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, your solution for multiple clients works perfectly! Thank you so much!